# Program to determine the relationship of one variable to several possible variables

Tags: functional-equations, integer-programming

Suppose I have a system with several variables a, b, c, d, and x. I am trying to solve for the unknown x. I don't know exactly which of those variables x is dependent on, or exactly how the function works, but I know that it is dependent on *some combination of some of those variables*. To help me determine the function, I have a few data points where I know what the value of x should be, e.g.:

- If a = 2, b = 1, c = 4, and d = 3, then x = 8
- If a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, and d = 4, then x = 14
- If a = 3, b = 4, c = 2, and d = 1, then x = -3

In this case, one possible function that satisfies the requirements would be `x = (d^2) - b`. Note that this function completely ignores variables a and c. That's fine: maybe a and c are extraneous to the function. What I'm looking for is a program where I can plug in those variables along with the data points I know to be correct, and have it churn through the myriad possible functions that combine them variables until it finds a function that satisfies all the data points.

Now I realize that in theory, the number of possible functions that the program would have to check is probably unlimited. But with a few default constraints I believe the total search space wouldn't be that big. For example, for my particular problem I could eliminate anything more complex that quadratic (variable ^ 2), or more generally, I could eliminate any function where a variable is used more than twice. (And I strongly suspect that my particular problem has a linear solution.)

This sounds a little bit like curve-plot-fitting, which apparently can be done in programs like Matlab, but all the examples I've seen of that technique show a 2D (x and y) graph, whereas I need something more general and flexible, supporting more than 2 variables. Does anyone know of such a program? And I'm a programmer myself, so if you know of a general algorithm, I might be able to implement it.

(Note: I'm just guessing at the category tags for this question; my math knowledge is limited to high-school calculus.)

Comment: Sounds like a problem for the RIES tool: http://mrob.com/pub/ries/

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, neat tool, but it doesn't seem to support multiple variables with separate values producing a single value. Instead it just lets you enter the single value and then it comes up with a bunch of equations based on static values that can equal your value. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I've never used so I wouldn't know, but I thought it was worth a shot

Comment: This kind of problem is made much easier if you know what kind of relationship you're looking for.  You can certainly fit equations to data, even with multiple variables, and find the best, for example, "linear" or "quadratic" fit.  Not sure what program to use though.